# javascript array filter with only index

Tags: javascript

I have an arry like this:

```
0: File
1: File
2: File
length: 3
__proto__: FileList
```

Here every file which are in list contains `filename` dictionary..
How can I get only array with index like 0,1,2 and not length and **proto** . I want the list which contains name from `File` array

I am new to javascript

Comment: Can you provide a demo ? What is the input ?

Comment: Believe me, you don't need to remove `length` from an JavaScript `Array` and you certainly don't want to remove `__proto__` from an `Object`. These properties are root of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an arry like this
>
> ```
> 0: File
> 1: File
> 2: File
> length: 3
> __proto__: FileList
> ```
>
> I want the list which contains name from `File` array

[`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object is not an `Array`; [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) object is not an `Array`. You can create an array, iterate `FileList` object and push `.name` property of each `File` object in `FileList` object to the created array

```
for (var i = 0, names = []; i < files.length; i++) {
  names.push(files[i].name)
}
console.log(names);
```

or select specific `File` within `FileList` using the `index` and `.item()`; for example to retrieve `.name` of `File` at `index` `2`

```
var name = files.item(2).name;
```

Comment: To create `Array` from `Array-Like Object` on single line you can use `var filesAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(files)` and in ES6 we have `Array.from()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility function in underscoreJS.
`_.pluck(arrayOfObjects, property)`. Check out `_.pluck` from `http://underscorejs.org/#pluck`